# iPad web app - can't select/copy/paste into an input field after CSS transform

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, css

All,

I'm working on a web app (exclusively for the iPad) that uses a modified version of the Coda Slider (http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/).

One of the sliding panels includes a text box.

When I use the unmodified version of the slider, it works great. I can click the text box to get focus, and the iOS select/copy/paste functions work as usual.

However, by default, the Coda Slider uses jquery.animate(). Since I'm targeting the iPad exclusively, I decided to replace animate() with CSS3, -webkit-transition, -webkit-transform, and translate3d. The result is MUCH smoother animation, since tranlate3d is hardware accelerated.

As part of my modification, I'm adjusting the "left" style instead of "marginLeft" (the property that Coda Slider animates by default).

So far - so good. Everything works as I'd hoped.

The only problem - while I'm still able to click the input text box to focus in it (and the keyboard works still works to let me type) - the Select/Copy/Paste functions don't work.

In other words - you can type in the field, but if you tap and hold - you don't get the Select/Copy/Paste pop-up menu.

For those not familiar with the Coda Slider - in short - each "panel" of the slider is a div, and all panels are wrapped in a container div. The animation works by moving the container div left and right within a wrapper div with overflow set to hidden.

As I mentioned - by default, the Coda slider moves the container div left and right by adjusting it's marginLeft property.

So long as I keep that behavior - the select/copy/paste works fine. As soon as I change it to use the "left" property instead of "marginLeft" - select/copy/paste stops working.

Has anyone run into this issue before? I don't know if the issue is specific to my implementation, my modification of the default Coda Slider code, or something else.

Many thanks in advance for any advice or insight.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a problem with apples hook into webkit for these long press events for the magnifier and copy paste etc.

It is clear from a little experiment that translate3d positions are simply discounted.

the only work around I have found is to immediately update with left and top as soon as the animation has finished, and remove the translate3d (as that is added to left and right). you need to be very careful with absolute and relative positions of the whole tree that your element is in. Remember that absolute is absolutely relative to the closes absolutely positioned parent.

this simple bit of markup can demonstrate my findings:

```
        <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <div>
                    <input type="text" name="fart" value="fart" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(000px, 0px, 0px); width: 300px; height: 40px;"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <input type="text" name="fart1" value="fart1" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(50px, 0px, 0px); width: 300px; height: 40px;"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <input type="text" name="fart2" value="fart2" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px); width: 300px; height: 40px;"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <input type="text" name="fart3" value="fart3" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(300px, 0px, 0px); width: 300px; height: 40px;"></input>
            </div>

            <div>
                    <div style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);">
                            <input type="text" name="fart4" value="fart4" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;"></input>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                    <div style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 100px, 0px);">
                            <input type="text" name="fart5" value="fart5" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;"></input>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div style="left: 10px; top: 300px; position: absolute;">
                    <div style="left: 10px; top: 100px; position: absolute;">
                            <input type="text" name="fart6" value="fart6" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;"></input>
                    </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

I am sure it should be classed as a bug